# Rounded list item with different background color on right side

Tags: android-layout

This is what I try to achieve:
[image]

The amount of text will determine how large portion of the list item that should have the blueish background color.

I try to achieve this with a selector but then I end up with a blueish square where the uttermost parts are grey. Like this:

[image]

Any ideas how this can be done in a simple way? I.e. preferrably using XML only.

This is my approach (yields second picture):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:constantSize="true"
      android:variablePadding="false">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_round_grey"/>

</selector>
```

and:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    tools:background="@drawable/btn_round_grey"
    >

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/grey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/grey"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/list_item_padding"
            >

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/list_item_padding"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="TEXT"
                />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output by the following code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/roundcorner_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/half_roundcorner_selector"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="TEdasdadaXT" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

roundcorner_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</shape>
```

half_roundcorner_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

</shape>
```

You can modify this as per your requirements.

In your code you need to set the custom drawable for the `TextView`. Because by setting the color as background it will take as square.

Comment: "in your code you need to set the custom drawable for the TextView"

Custom drawable? You mean `setBackgroundResource()` ?

Comment: Are you setting the `TextView` background programatically? If so, you can set the shape drawable through setBackgroundResource()

Comment: I managed to get it to work the way I wanted thanks to your answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: The reason I failed: I had some padding in my drawable. So stupid :-(